# How to find the tangent of a curve knowing the function $f(x)$?

Tags: color

I have 10 values for y and 10 for x, therefore a curve was created from these values. I need, somehow, to find the tangent of this curve. May there is a option in Mathematica or something similar?

Comment: Use [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) on the data and take the derivative of the [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html)

Answer (score 2):

I generate the data (I have none) to simulate what you have, and interpolate to obtain the function:

```
data = N@Table[{i, Exp[-i] Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 9}];
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> "Spline"];
```

Then represent the function describing your data and its derivative (the tangent to $f(x)$ at every $x$, where is defined and smooth, of course) as usually you derive any other function :

```
Plot[{f[x], f'[x]}, {x, 0, 9}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]